# How can I import 83 email addresses to outlook contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am running Outlook 2007 on Windows 8. I received an email with 83 CC addresses.
How can I batch-import these into my Outlook address book? I don't want to have to do these one by one, UGH!

Comment: batch import the addresses, or names and addresses? Do they all have names?

Comment: Do you want to save them as individual contacts or as a distribution list?

Comment: You still might have to resort to saving those emails in a CSV file and then import that into the Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but the solution may not be quicker than right-clicking each one and selecting 'add to contacts'.

The page spelling it out is [here](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/485), and the general method is:

1. First create a distribution list by copying the list of addresses from the headers, as per [this page](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/484)
2. Save the distribution list as a file; this will give us something we can import in a later step
3. Edit the file to change the headers at the top to `Full Name` and `E-mail Address`
4. Import the file as a new set of contacts (using tab-separated values as the format)

They also link to an addin, which might be something you want to consider if you do this often.

Comment: Thank you. Its such a logical requirement, Outlook should cater for it. I have received many similar mails over the years.

Comment: I agree! In fact, [Outlook 2010 added a feature called 'Suggested Contacts'](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-add-contacts-for-everyone-that-you-send-an-email-message-HA101874367.aspx) which is a contacts folder which automatically populates with any contacts you send mail to, but who aren't in your normal contacts list. This only works if you _send_ mail to those people - e.g. if you did a reply-all to your 83-person email.  It appears it was removed in Outlook 2013 because people hated it.

Answer (score 0):

To Batch import the new contacts to your contacts, you will need to create a CSV file then use the Outlook import from file feature.

Below I listed how to create a CSV file and how to import from a file in Outlook:

Go [HERE](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12119?hl=en) for how to create a CSV file.

Go [HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/import-contacts-HA101870645.aspx) for How to Import contacts from CSV.